# Not inserting where i expected

Tags: php, mysql

In a mysql table, i have 3 fields. user_to, user_from and id. The variables are all correct and should be inserting the correct data.

When a button is clicked, named 'poke', it should insert the cookie that stores the session of who did it and the person who was poked. It doesn't seem to be inserting and I am stuck :(

```
                    $cookie = $_SESSION['user_login'];
 //Poke code
 if (@$_POST['poke']) {
 $check_if_poked = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pokes WHERE user_to='$username' && user_from='$added_by'");
 $num_poke_found = mysql_num_rows($check_if_poked);

 if ($num_poke_found == 1) {
 echo "Come on! Give the guy a chance!";
 }
 else
 if ($username == $cookie) {
 echo "You cannot Jab yourself.";
 }
 else
 { $poke_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pokes` ('user_from', 'user_to') VALUES ('$cookie', '$username')") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
  echo "$username has been jabbed.";
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, you might want to put the condition where you check if `$username == $cookie` first in your order of operations.  There is no reason to even call the DB if this condition is true.

Comment: how do you reference to the `$username` with `else` after the database `if` ?

Comment: what does mysql_error produce? Also - not a good idea to suppress $_POST like that. You should use if(isset($_POST['poke']))

Comment: Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: and if the `($username == $cookie)` how are you inserting it in the database for the same fields, `user_from` and `user_to`?

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong quotes with fields in MySQL query.

```
//your wrong variant
"INSERT INTO `pokes` ('user_from', 'user_to') VALUES ('$cookie', '$username')"

//right variant
"INSERT INTO `pokes` (`user_from`, `user_to`) VALUES ('$cookie', '$username')"
```

Quotes like ' mean values and quotes like ` mean fields in SQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_POST['poke']) {
 #ref to the current user
 $from = $_SESSION['user_login'];
 #ref to the (poked user)
 $to = $_POST['poked_user_id'];

 if($from == $to){
    echo "you cant poke yourself!";
 }
 else{
    #ADVICE: USE PDO OR MYSQLI INSTEAD OF MYSQL

    $check_if_poked = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pokes WHERE user_to='$to' AND user_from='$from'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($check_if_poked)){
        echo "Come on! Give the guy a chance!";
    }
    else{
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pokes` (`user_from`, `user_to`) VALUES ('$from', '$to')")){
            echo "$to has been jabbed.";
        }
        else{
        trigger_error(mysql_error());
        }
    }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This started off as a comment - but it's getting too long to fit.

A session is not the same thing as a username - your post is very confused.

Leaving aside the wrong quotes (which is why your code is not doing what you expect)....

> In a mysql table, i have 3 fields. user_to, user_from and id

... in that case you don't need to check if the row already exists - and not create duplicates. Set up a unique index then...

```
if (@$_POST['poke'] && ($_SESSION['user_login']!===$username)) {
   $qry = "INSERT INTO `pokes` (`user_from`, `user_to`) 
          VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_login'])
          .", '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "')"
   if (mysql_query($qry)){
      echo "$username has been jabbed.";
   } else if (stristr(mysql_error(), 'duplicate')) {
      echo "Come on! Give the guy a chance!";
   } else {
      echo "It's all gone Pete Tong!";
   }
 } else if ($_SESSION['user_login']!===$username) {
    echo "You cannot Jab yourself.";
 }
```

While it's about the same effort for PHP processing, the DB workload is significantly less. This code also prevents some SQL injection attacks, and has error handling. I presume that $username has been created elsewhere and you don't have register_globals enabled.